# алгоритм поиска номера элемента в списке

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть отсортированный по полю "продукт" список объектов следующего вида:

```
{"Завод1", "нефть"},
{"Завод2", "нефть"},
{"Завод3", "газ"},
{"Завод4", "газ"},
{"Завод5", "газ"},
{"Завод6", "бензин"}
```

и тд. и есть список с объектами, в которых хранится итог по каждому продукту:

```
{"нефть", "-"},
{"бензин", "-"},
{"газ", "-"}.
```

Список с итоговыми обхектами перебирается в цикле и вставляется с помощью Insert в первый список, чтобы получился тако список

```
{"Завод1", "нефть"},
{"Завод2", "нефть"},
{"нефть", "-"},
{"Завод3", "газ"},
{"Завод4", "газ"},
{"Завод5", "газ"},
{"газ", "-"},
{"Завод6", "бензин"}
{"бензин", "-"}.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, наилучший алгоритм для определения номера позиции, по которому должны добавляться итоговые объекты, чтобы передавать этот метод в Insert()

Comment: используйте цикл и сравнение строк, должно нормально отработать

Comment: так и работает все) но хотелось бы что-нибудь красивее, может через линк как-нибудь

Comment: То есть у вас есть код и вы спрашиваете, как его переписать красивее? Чтобы это понять, надо видеть ваш код.

Comment: в цикле for сравнивается i-ый элемент с i+1-ым, если они разные, то в if проверяем подходит ли по значению

Comment: Если вам нужен поиск по данным, то используйте словарь или хешсет. Если вам нужна группировка, то используйте `Linq` и `GroupBy`